# Centering div like in the image

Tags: html, css

How can I center this `div` (in the image) so that it remains responsive? (without margin)

[image]

```html
<div id="featured-work">
   <h2>FEATURED WORK</h2>
   <p>Proin iaculis purus consequat sem cure digni ssim. Donec porttitora entum suscipit
aenean rhoncus posuere odio in tincidunt. Proin iaculis purus consequat sem cure
digni ssim. Donec porttitora entum suscipit. </p>
    <div id="featured-work-list">
      <div class="list1">
       <h3>Title 1</h3>
       <span>Proin iaculis purus digni consequat sem digni<br> ssim. Donec entum digni ssim.</span>
      </div>
      <div class="list2"> 
       <h3>Title 2</h3>
       <span>Proin iaculis purus digni consequat sem digni<br> ssim. Donec entum digni ssim.</span>
      </div>
      <div class="list3"> 
       <h3>Title 3</h3>
       <span>Proin iaculis purus digni consequat sem digni<br> ssim. Donec entum digni ssim.</span>
      </div>
      <div class="list4"> 
       <h3>Title 4</h3>
       <span>Proin iaculis purus digni consequat sem digni<br> ssim. Donec entum digni ssim.</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="featured_work" class="pull-left">
```

in css

```
.pull-left{
    float: left;
    }
```